# Delphi DeHL Deserialize XML File in newer class?

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-serialization, delphi-2010, dehl

I use DeHL to serilize XML and class in Delphi and if add property to my class and try to deserialize my XML file. I have this error : ‘Deserializing « \TApp\FObject\test » failed. Serializer reported it’s missing or other entity is currently read!’.

I understand quite well this problem but is there a way to put default value instead of error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex answer me this :

> You should be able to — by annotating
>   the “part2″ field with [XmlNullable].
>   This will tell the XML serializer to
>   set the “part2″ field to NIL if it
>   does not have an XML node.
>
> Note that while this is possible it’s
>   not recommended. Deserialized content
>   should be serialized back to the
>   original types otherwise “bad things”
>   may happen.

I ask this question a long time ago on his site but I was not able to find where I ask this question : http://alex.ciobanu.org/?p=285#comments